# unable to SSH to eth1 after bringing down eth0

Tags: ssh, ethernet, network-interface, sshd

I have a remote machine with 2 interfaces: `eth0` and `eth1`.

I am able to ssh using eth0 ip address as well as eth1 ip addr. However, things go strange once I bring down eth0 using the command `ifdown eth0`. After pulling down eth0, I am able to ping eth1 but I am no longer able to ssh using eth1. I checked the ssh config but couldn't find anything related to interface configuration.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you running a firewall that might be blocking traffic to port 22 on eth1?  If you use `ss -l` or `netstat -l` can you see anything listening on port 22?

Comment: what's the error message?

Comment: What's the routing table? You should have two default routes: via eth0 and via eth1. The default route via eth0 should have a smaller metric that the default route via eth1.  Otherwise when you drop eth0 there will be no way for a packet to get back to your machine from eth1 (assuming your machine is further than the connected subnet).  See the command `ip route show` and `ip -6 route show`.  You are looking for a result along the lines of `default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0  metric 1`, `default via 192.168.2.1 dev eth1  metric 2`, adjusting the IP addressing for your own subnets' routers.

Comment: @vk5tu when i do ip route show, i see 
default via <ip-addr> dev eth0

does that mean if eth0 goes off, i will have no way to reach via ssh even if eth1 is active.?
do i need to see another "default via.. dev eth1" entry

Comment: @cool77. Yep, when eth0 goes down the routes to via that interface are invalidated. Then you're left with no route beyond your immediate subnet.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have 2 devices with the same subnet. This generally works badly/unexpectedly. You need to have different subnets, or you have to disable ARP.

eg. To disable ARP:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/arp_ignore
echo 2 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/arp_announce
```

But I'm sure there's a better approach to whatever problem you have. Maybe you should make a bridge and use only one IP address. For example:

```
brctl addbr br0
brctl addif br0 eth0
brctl addif br0 eth1
ip a add ... dev br0
```

Or two addresses on the same NIC, or 2 different subnets (eg. 192.168.123.0/24 and 192.168.124.0/24).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you left some ListenAddress directive in sshd conf?
In my setups when i want multi-interface access i just comment out lines:

```
ListenAddress ::
ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: i checked my sshd_config file but it does'nt have ListenAddress directive.